# How to use gcc atomic builtins?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc

In my program I was trying to update a value from multiple threads. I know how to use mutex (`pthread_mutex_lock(), pthread_mutex_unlock()`) to do this, but I just learned about gcc atomic builtins so I would like to have a try.

```
shared value A;
void each_working_thread() {
    thread local variable B;
    if (is_valid(A,B))
        __sync_sub_and_fetch(A,B);
    else 
        throw error;
}
```

where `is_valid()` is a const function that return boolean.

Is this correct, or the value of A could be updated by another thread during `is_valid()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume is_valid(A, B) can change depending on A.

In which case, this is not safe - consider the following sequence:

- Thread 1 calls `is_valid(A, B)` and gets true
- Thread 2 calls `is_valid(A, B)` and gets true
- Thread 1 calls `__sync_sub_and_fetch(A, B)` changes A, and the new value of A means `is_valid(A, B)` is now false.
- Thread 2 calls `__sync_sub_and_fetch(A, B)` even though it shouldn't because `is_valid(A, B)` is now false.

You may be interested in the *compare-exchange* operation. In this case you can write something like:

```
int oldValueOfA, newValueOfA;
do {
    oldValueOfA = A;
    __sync_synchronize(); // memory barrier; makes sure A doesn't get accessed after this line
    if (!is_valid(oldValueOfA, B))
        throw error;
    newValueOfA = oldValueOfA - B;
} while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&A, oldValueOfA, newValueOfA));
```

You can't make the two operations atomic, but you can detect *if they weren't atomic* and then you can try again.

This works because if `A` doesn't still contain `oldValueOfA`, `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` does nothing and returns false. Otherwise, it sets it to `newValueOfA` and returns true. So if it returns true, you know nobody else changed `A` while you were busy calling `is_valid`. And if it returns false, then you haven't actually done anything yet, so you're free to go back and try again.

Note that `is_valid` might be called several times; this is relevant if it has side effects (like printing a message on the screen). In that case you should just use a mutex.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. so do I have to use a mutex in this case? Is there any difference if  `is_valid` is just `return A>B;` or is a quite complex function that need hundreds of instructions?

Comment: @bbvan Do you think the thing I described can still happen if `is_valid` is just `return A>B;`? If not, why not? The fact that you're asking *suggests* you haven't really thought about my explanation.

Comment: yes i think there is no difference... but i was hoping there is something magic atomic operations like `sync_if_cmpgt_then_sub` ...

Answer (score 0):

That probably is not thread safe, depending on what exactly is_valid does.

The point of that specific builtin is just to perform an atomic subtraction.

Consider this code

```
A = A - B;
```

This is not thread safe because it requires at least 2 atomic steps - the A - B, and then the assignment back to A. The builtin for this solves that one scenario.